# C# Webbrowser Click on Javascript Button

Tags: c#, javascript, html, browser

I need a help with a problem:

My Page is written in html and javascript.

When i use `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("hmenu").InvokeMember("click");` this menu opens on my screen but I don't know what I must use to click the button writed javascript it is selected on image
http://www.bankfotek.pl/view/1153142

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to invoke click onto the button?
I believe you need to assign a id to the button, then invoke it by doing

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("hmenu.ID").InvokeMember("click");
```

Hope that works